# Trigonometric limit $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\cos(a+2x) - 2\cos(a+x) + \cos(a)}{x^2}$ without l'Hospital

Tags: calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

Compute the following limit:

$$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\cos(a+2x) - 2\cos(a+x) + \cos(a)}{x^2}\   .$$

How would I go about solving this problem?
I can't use l'Hospital.

Comment: I repeat myself: do not double post.

Answer (score 1):

Simply expand:
$$
\cos(a+2x) = \cos a \cos(2x) - \sin a\sin(2x) 
= 2\cos a \cos^2 x - \cos a  - 2\sin a\sin x \cos x
\\
\cos(a+x) = \cos a \cos x - \sin a\sin x 
$$
Putting things together, you find
$$
\frac{
2\cos a \cos^2 x  - 2\sin a\sin x \cos x - 2 \cos a \cos x + 2 \sin a\sin x 
}{x^2}
$$
Now use the fact that
$$
\frac{1-\cos u}{u^2}\to \frac 12
$$to conclude.

Answer (score 0):

$$\cos (a+2x) -2\cos (a+x) +\cos a = \cos (a+2x) -\cos (a+x) -(\cos (a+x) -\cos a) =-2\sin \left(a+\frac{3x}{2}\right)\sin\frac{x}{2} +2\sin \left(a+\frac{x}{2} \right)\sin\frac{x}{2} =-4\sin\frac{x}{2}\sin\frac{x}{2}\cos (a+x) $$ hence $$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\cos (a+2x) -2\cos (a+x) +\cos a}{x^2} =\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{-4\sin^2\frac{x}{2} \cos(x+a)}{x^2} =-\cos a$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $m = a+x.$ Then
$$\begin{eqnarray}
\cos(a+2x) - 2\cos(a+x) + \cos(a)
&=& \cos(m+x) - 2\cos m + \cos(m-x) \\
&=& \cos m \cos x - \sin m \sin x - 2\cos m + \cos m \cos x + \sin m \sin x \\
&=& 2 (\cos m)(\cos x - 1) \\
&=& 2 \cos(a+x)(\cos x - 1).
\end{eqnarray}$$
You are therefore trying to find
$$\lim_{x\to 0} \left(2 \cos(a+x) \frac{\cos x - 1}{x^2}\right)
= 2 \left(\lim_{x\to 0} \cos(a+x)\right)\left(\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\cos x - 1}{x^2}\right).$$